# Dynamic subscription not receiving data on the client after parameters change

Tags: javascript, meteor

Currently trying to change a subscription for an existing page so that the result can be influenced by a serie of filter the user can set on the client

Code on the client looks like this template-wise

**onCreated**

```
Template.primeentry.onCreated(function () {
    let self = this
    this.selectedCompany = Meteor.user().profile.im3core.selectedusergroup;
    this.subscribe('im3coredocumenttype.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3coredocument.allDocsPayments', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corepaymentmode.allFilteredToModes', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corepartnertype.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corepricelist.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corepartner.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corewarehouse.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corecontact.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3coreaccount.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corevat.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corefiscalretention.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3corecompany.mine');

    this.subscribe('im3coremoneysearch.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany })
    this.subscribe('im3coremoneytransactionManual.all', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany });
    this.subscribe('im3coreprimeEntryManualModes', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany })
    this.subscribe('im3.core.primeEntryPreviousTotals', { "__im3coreOwnership.groups": this.selectedCompany })

    this.showTotalColumns = new ReactiveVar(false);
    this.totalBalance = new ReactiveVar(0);
    this.totalAmount = new ReactiveVar(0);
    this.supplier_clientSelector = new ReactiveVar("-1")
    this.supplier_clientId = new ReactiveVar("-1")

    let newDateYear = new Date().getFullYear() + 1
    this.toDateIso = new ReactiveVar(new Date(newDateYear, 0, 1))
    this.fromDateIso = new ReactiveVar(new Date(newDateYear - 1, 0, 1))
    this.userId = Meteor.userId()
    this.im3money = im3core.im3money
    this.paymentModes = im3core.im3money.fatturaElettronicaenaledPaymentModes
    this.addrows = new ReactiveVar([{ destinations: 1 }])
    this.accountsList = new ReactiveVar([])
    this.accountTotals = []
    this.accountFromId = new ReactiveVar("-1")
    this.Refresh = new ReactiveVar(true)
    this.transactionsList = new ReactiveVar()
    this.moveToLine = -1
    this.PrefilterLine = []
    this.previousData = new ReactiveVar({})
    this.limit = new ReactiveVar(20)
    this.skip = new ReactiveVar(0)
    this.alreadyPassed = false;
    this.autorun(() => {
        this.subscribe('im3coremoneytransactions.allForPrimeEntry', {
            '__im3coreOwnership.groups': this.selectedCompany,
            "date": {
                $gte: new Date(this.fromDateIso.get()),
                $lte: new Date(this.toDateIso.get())
            }
        }, {
            sort: { date: -1 },
            limit: this.limit.get(),
            skip: this.skip.get()
        })
    })
    Meteor.call('UpdatePreviousYear', this.selectedCompany, new Date().getFullYear(), this.limit.get(), function (err, result) {
        console.log("runsetup ==>", err || result);
        if (err) {

        } else {
            self.previousData.set(result)
            let valuesList = GetAccountsRender(self)
            console.log("valuesList", valuesList)
            SetupAccountTotalsWithPreviousYearsRender(valuesList, self);
            self.Refresh.set(false)
        }
    });

    //im3primeentry.accountsList=this.accountsList
})
```

**onRendered**

```
Template.primeentry.onRendered(function () {
    let instance = this
    let dateFrom = instance.fromDateIso.get()
    let yyyy = String(new Date(dateFrom).getFullYear())
    let mm = new Date(dateFrom).getMonth() + 1 > 9 ? String(new Date(dateFrom).getMonth() + 1) : "0" + String(new Date(dateFrom).getMonth() + 1)
    let dd = new Date(dateFrom).getDate() > 9 ? String(new Date(dateFrom).getDate()) : "0" + String(new Date(dateFrom).getDate())
    $("#fromDate").val(yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd)
    let dateTo = instance.toDateIso.get()
    let year = String(new Date(dateTo).getFullYear())
    let month = new Date(dateTo).getMonth() + 1 > 9 ? String(new Date(dateTo).getMonth() + 1) : "0" + String(new Date(dateTo).getMonth() + 1)
    let day = new Date(dateTo).getDate() > 9 ? String(new Date(dateTo).getDate()) : "0" + String(new Date(dateTo).getDate())
    $("#toDate").val(year + "-" + month + "-" + day)

    instance.autorun(() => {
        let isRefreshing = instance.Refresh.get()

        if (this.subscriptionsReady() && isRefreshing == false && instance.alreadyPassed == false) {
            let valueList = Template.instance().accountsList.get()
            console.log("valuelist onrender", valueList)
            /* let valuesList = GetAccounts()
            console.log("valuesList", valuesList)
            SetupAccountTotalsWithPreviousYears(valuesList); */
            let im3money = instance.im3money
            let company = Template.instance().selectedCompany
            Template.instance().registerAccount = im3core.accountCollection.findOne({ "__im3coreOwnership.groups": company, isRegister: true })
            let transactionFilterDateFrom = new Date(Template.instance().fromDateIso.get())
            let transactionFilterDateTo = new Date(Template.instance().toDateIso.get())

            let result = [];
            if (typeof company != "undefined") {
                let transactionsList = GetTransactions(im3money, instance)
                transactionsList.forEach(transaction => {
                
                //code i'm omitting because it's not relevant to the problem

                })
            }
            
            

            instance.alreadypassed = true
        }
    })
})
```

**The GetTransactions function**

```
function GetTransactions(im3money, instance) {
    return im3money.moneytransactionsCollection.find({
         '__im3coreOwnership.groups': instance.selectedCompany,
            "date": {
                $gte: new Date(instance.fromDateIso.get()),
                $lte: new Date(instance.toDateIso.get())
            }
        }, {
            sort: { date: -1 },
            limit: instance.limit.get(),
            skip: instance.skip.get()
    }).fetch();
}
```

Now,the page has 4 controls (2 buttons and 2 date inputs) and the corresponding events to update dates and skip ReactiveVars

**Events**

```
    "change #fromDate": function (event, instance) {
        let x = $(event.currentTarget).val()
        let dateSplit = x.split('-')
        let dateValue = new Date(dateSplit[0], +dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[2])
        instance.fromDateIso.set(dateValue)

    },
    "change #toDate": function (event, instance) {
        let x = $(event.currentTarget).val()
        let dateSplit = x.split('-')
        let dateValue = new Date(dateSplit[0], +dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[2])
        instance.toDateIso.set(dateValue)
    },
    "click .pageBack": function (event, instance) {
        let current = +instance.skip.get()
        current += 20
        instance.skip.set(current)
    },
    "click .pageNext": function (event, instance) {
        let current = +instance.skip.get()
        if (current >= 20) {
            current -= 20
            instance.skip.set(current)
        }
    }
```

Nothing fancy enough that i'd expect it to create problems.

But...

When the page first loads with the default ReactiveVars setup,everything works. The client receives data from the 'im3coremoneytransactions.allForPrimeEntry' subscription as expected.

After that,if i change the date values using the input controls,everything still works and the client gets the new values included within the selected date range

As soon as i try to change the skip value, GetTransaction on the client return an empty array.

I know the server's publish is receiving the changed parameters correctly since i have a line inside it to log what's going to be sent to the client and everything shows up as it should on that front (i.e. the server log shows me an array of transactions that correctly skips the updates number of records)

I'm pretty sure i'm overlooking something very basic here but the fact that the date switching works and only the skip change does not is throwing me for a loop(i'd expect either both type of filter to either work or return as empty instead of acting the opposite way) and i can't pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your reactive data source into the auto run like below.

```
...
this.autorun(() => {
       this.selectedCompany = Meteor.user().profile.im3core.selectedusergroup;
        this.subscribe('im3coremoneytransactions.allForPrimeEntry', {
            '__im3coreOwnership.groups': this.selectedCompany,
            "date": {
                $gte: new Date(this.fromDateIso.get()),
                $lte: new Date(this.toDateIso.get())
            }
        }, {
            sort: { date: -1 },
            limit: this.limit.get(),
            skip: this.skip.get()
        })
    })
...
```

Comment: That makes sense but i'm left with a doubt.If that's the case,why does it work as it is when the dates get changed?

Comment: No need to doubt just read the documentation https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html

Answer (score 0):

Well,forgot to follow up saying that i found the problem and it was incredibly silly as i feared.

I was applying a skip to the result i got from the publish that was exactly the same value i was using as limit in the publish itself.Meaning the final value obviously showed up empty